# Count the Frequency of X letter words?

Tags: java, algorithm

i have to create a program where it counts the frequency/occurrence of X letter of words, i have got the program to work out the frequency of the words and the lengths but now i need to work out the mean length of the words entered, i am really stuck on this so if anyone can help i will be grateful

This is the code i have as of yet:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CountLetters {
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a sentence." );
    int amount = 0;
    String output = "Amount of letters:\n";

    for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
        char letter = input.charAt(i);
        amount++;
        output = input;
    }
    output += "\n" + amount;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, output,
                         "Letters", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE ); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mean is just `totalValue / totalCount`.

To do it as another loop at the end of your existing code:

Start with them both at 0.

```
long totalValue = 0;
long totalCount = 0;
```

So you need to loop through all of your word counts doing:

```
totalValue += wordLength * wordCount;
totalCount += wordCount;
```

Then at the end you just do:

```
float mean = (float)totalValue/totalCount;
```

Alternatively to calculate the mean at the same time as doing the main loop you can do:

```
totalValue += wordLength;
totalCount += 1;
```

Each time around the main loop once you have found a word.

Comment: I added that as a second option in the answer.

Comment: I have edited the code above to what i have tried to do but its coming back with a error?

Answer (score 1):

Use a map to map the word length to the number of times that word length occurs.

Then follow the multiplicative logic of Tim B's answer.

A quick example I threw together.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> wordLengths = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        final String testString = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
        final String[] words = testString.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            final int wordLength = words[i].length();

            if( wordLengths.keySet().contains( wordLength ) ) {
                Integer currentNumberOfOccurences = wordLengths.get(wordLength);
                currentNumberOfOccurences++;
                wordLengths.put(wordLength, currentNumberOfOccurences);
                continue;
            }

            wordLengths.put(wordLength, 1);
        }

        double totalLength = 0;
        double totalOccurrences = 0;
        for (final Integer length : wordLengths.keySet()) {
            final Integer occurrences = wordLengths.get(length);
            totalLength = totalLength + (length * occurrences );
            totalOccurrences += occurrences;
        }

        final double mean = totalLength / totalOccurrences;

        System.out.println("Average word length is: " + mean );
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about that on the mean? If you had 100 words 3 letters long and nothing else you would get a mean of 0.03 with your algorithm...

Comment: @dan still wrong unfortunately :( you will need to multiply the key and value together. See my answer.

Comment: @TimB called me on it again! :)    I've written a test and indeed you're correct.

Comment: This code isnt calculating the mean though? its calculating the average?

Comment: sorry my bad it is, but its rounding it up to the nearest whole number, how can i stop it from doing that and give a decimal if need be?

Comment: @user3356827 - So it does, I've edited it to provide the solution as a double. Note, the `totalLength` and `totalOccurrences` fields are now also defined as doubles.