# Frequency of X letter words in text

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a program to count the frequency of 1 letter, 2 letter, etc. words in a given text file.  However, it only appears to work with small files.

I looked up some solutions(which I don't completely understand) involving arrays and incorporated them into the code.  When I tested a file with a few words, it worked, but when given a large file, like the entirety of Romeo and Juliet, it gives the wrong results.

(Also, what is "for(String str : strings)" doing?)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Authorship
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            try
            {
                    System.out.print("Name of input file: ");
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String name = in.nextLine();
                    File text = new File(name);
                    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(text);
                    String line = in2.nextLine();
                    String[] strings = line.split(" ");
                    int[] counts = new int[14];
                    for(String str : strings)
                    {
                            if (str.length() < counts.length)
                                    counts [str.length()] += 1;
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
                    {
                            System.out.print("Proportion of " + i + "-letter words: ");
                            System.out.println("( " + counts[i] + " words )");
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception FileNotFoundException)
            {
                    System.out.println("File not found");
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you're doing in your `catch` block is travesty. Don't ignore the exception and its message.

Comment: *what is "for(String str : strings)" doing?* It is called an enhanced for-loop or for-each, and it loops through the elements of an array/collection, not through index.

Comment: Adding on @SotiriosDelimanolis comment: [Here's why](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) it's a travesty. A stack trace can be very valuable.

Comment: what means `it gives the wrong results`?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047855/count-the-frequency-of-x-letter-words?rq=1

Comment: Thanks guys.  Also, "it gives the wrong results" means that it's counting the wrong number of each word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enhanced For loop is covered in Chapter 14. Blocks and Statements of the JLS ([jls-14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)), and it says (in part) -

> The meaning of the enhanced for statement is given by translation into a basic for statement, as follows: 
>   ...
>   the Expression necessarily has an array type, T[].
>   Let L1 ... Lm be the (possibly empty) sequence of labels immediately preceding the enhanced for statement.
>
> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> T[] #a = Expression;
> L1: L2: ... Lm:
> for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>     {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>     Statement
> }
> ```

Also, this

```
 catch (Exception e) // FileNotFoundException)
 {
   System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Finally, your program is operating on one line at a time. If you want to operate on all of the lines you will need to move the output loop after the catch, and put `int[] counts = new int[14];` before the try.

```
int[] counts = new int[14];
try {
  // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) { // <-- and arrays start at 0.
  System.out.print("Proportion of " + (i+1) + "-letter words: ");
  System.out.println("( " + counts[i] + " words )");
}
```

**Edit**

```
Scanner in2 = new Scanner(text);
String line;
while ((line = in2.nextLine()) != null) { // <-- read all the lines
  String[] strings = line.split(" ");
  for (String str : strings) {
    if (str.length() < counts.length) {
      counts[str.length()]++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the comments.  But I still can't seem to figure out why it's working for a short file, and giving absurd results (mostly zero) for anything larger...

Comment: @syhark How many lines are in your short file? Remember your's works one line at a time...

Comment: One.  So I moved the output loop and the int[] counts, but the same thing happens

Comment: Next time try a debugger. I don't have access to your [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_linguistics). Actually, hang on. Found it, you only read the first line of any input too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons countMatches method-

```
 StringUtils.countMatches(String string, String subStringToCount).
```

For ex-

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches("String string".toUpperCase(), "S"));
```

gives output = 2.